# Remove empty string field from a object contain nested object and array?

Tags: javascript

I have ask another question, but someone close that question. I really need this answer. That's why I asking another question.

I have a object like following. I have to remove that empty string filed from nested object and also from nested array. How can I remove that.

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Red Boy',
  price: '350',
  originalPrice: '', // Empty string field
  stock: 20,
  category: {
    name: '', // Empty String field
    subCategory: { name: ''} // Empty String filed 
  },
  weight: '90kg',
  dimensions: {
    width: '50cm',
    height: '', // Empty string filed
    length: '70cm'
  },
  suitable: [
     { name: 'Yoga' },
     { name: '' }, // Empty String filed
     { name: 'Winter' }
  ],
  additionalInfo: [
     { field: 'closure', value: 'Button' },
     { field: 'collar', value: ''} // Empty String Field 
  ]
}
```

In this hybrid object type you can see some sub-object and also some sub-array. You can also see some field that are not contain any value.(I comment out that filed).

Actually I need to remove that filed. How can I remove that empty string field from above hybrid object type.

Thank you..

My Expected result-

```
{
  name: 'Red Boy',
  price: '350',
  // Removed
  stock: 20,
  category: {
    name: '', // Empty String field
    // Removed
  },
  weight: '90kg',
  dimensions: {
    width: '50cm',
    // Removed
    length: '70cm'
  },
  suitable: [
     { name: 'Yoga' },
     //Removed
     { name: 'Winter' }
  ],
  additionalInfo: [
     { field: 'closure', value: 'Button' },
     { field: 'collar', //Removed }
     // Here If this two filed is empty then should remove the whole object
     { field: '', value: '' }
     // Then should remove whole '{ field: '', value: '' }'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Red Boy',
  price: '350',
  originalPrice: '', // Empty string field
  stock: 20,
  category: {
    name: '', // Empty String field
    subCategory: { name: ''} // Empty String filed 
  },
  weight: '90kg',
  dimensions: {
    width: '50cm',
    height: '', // Empty string filed
    length: '70cm'
  },
  suitable: [
     { name: 'Yoga' },
     { name: '' }, // Empty String filed
     { name: 'Winter' }
  ],
  additionalInfo: [
     { field: 'closure', value: 'Button' },
     { field: 'collar', value: ''} // Empty String Field 
  ]
}

function removeEmptyString(object) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value && typeof value === 'object')
                removeEmptyString(value);
            if (value && 
                typeof value === 'object' && 
                !Object.keys(value).length || 
                value === null || 
                value === undefined ||
                value.length === 0
            ) {
                if (Array.isArray(object))
                    object.splice(key, 1);
                else
                    delete object[key];
            }
        });
    return object;
}

console.log(removeEmptyString(obj))
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, we need to implement a recursive function to remove all empty string in all nested arrays and objects.

```js
function rec(obj){
    for(let key of Object.keys(obj)){
        if (obj[key] === ''){
            delete obj[key];
        }
        else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
            obj[key] = rec(obj[key]);
            if (Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0 ) delete obj[key];
        }
    }
    return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj.filter(val => val) : obj;
}
```

Also, please note that it's not purely hybrid. Because Array is special type of Object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an immutable way to remove non-empty values from an object, with the added capability of normalising object's inside of arrays:

```
const normaliseObject = (obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([_, value]) => value !== '' && value !== null)
      .map(([key, value]) => (typeof value === 'object' ? [key, normalise(value)] : [key, value])),
  )

// If an element in an array is an object, normalise that too
const normaliseArray = (arr) => arr.map(value => (typeof value === 'object' ? normalise(value) : value))

/**
 * Normalise any object to remove keys whose values are falsey
 * @param obj Object to be normalised
 * @returns Normalised object where falsey values are removed
 */
const normalise = (obj) => {
  return Array.isArray(obj) ? normaliseArray(obj) : normaliseObject(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `recursion` to filter out the `empty string`, `empty object` or `empty array` present deep inside the nested structure.

This function also removes such objects and their nested objects with no properties.

`Note: It will also work if the provided initial value is any other thing then object like array or string`

```js
var obj={name:"Red Boy",price:"350",originalPrice:"",stock:20,category:{name:"",subCategory:{name:""}},weight:"90kg",dimensions:{width:"50cm",height:"",length:"70cm"},suitable:[{name:"Yoga"},{name:""},{name:"Winter"}],additionalInfo:[{field:"closure",value:"Button"},{field:"collar",value:""}]};

function filt(a) {
  if (typeof a === 'string') return a !== '';
  //if it is a string, then it must not be empty
  else if (Array.isArray(a)) return a.length !== 0
  //if it an arra, then it must have some item
  else if (a instanceof Object) return Object.keys(a).length !== 0;
  //if it is an object, then it must have some property
  return a !== null && a !== undefined
  //else it must not be null or undefined
}

function rec(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    //if an value is an array
    return obj.map((a) => rec(a)).filter((a) => filt(a)) //recurse the child first of each value in the array
    //then filter out the value which are either null, empty, undefined or have length 0
  } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
    //if value is an object
    var d = Object.entries(obj).map((a) => ([a[0], rec(a[1])])).filter((a) => filt(a[1]));
    //map through the object.entries and reassign the values to the keys by recurssing over the value to filter out the nested inside irrelevant value
    return Object.fromEntries(d)
    //convert the map into object and return
  } else if (typeof obj === 'string') return obj !== '' ? obj : null
  //f it is a string, it must not be empty else return null
  return obj !== null && obj !== undefined ? obj : null
  //else it must not be null or undefined
}

console.log("For object",rec(obj))
console.log("For Array",rec([{
  name: "Yoga"
}, {
  name: ""
}, {
  name: "Winter"
}]))
```